# Prior corresponding to Elastic Net

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, elastic-net, bayesian-optimization

Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization : 
"elastic net is a regularized regression method that linearly combines the L1 and L2 penalties of the lasso and ridge methods."

L1-regularised learning corresponds to a MAP estimate with a Laplacian prior on the weights: p(w) ~ Laplace(0, b)

L2-regularised learning corresponds to a MAP estimate with a normal prior on the weights: p(w) ~ N(0, sigma^2)

I'm struggling to recognise the prior that gives rise to L1 + L2: p(w) ~ e^(a|w| + bw^2). Insight appreciated!

Comment: Came across this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4083.pdf which defines a "combined prior"", a mix of Gaussian and Laplace priors.